# Android ImageView Displays on Emulator but not on Device

Tags: android, android-layout

I am working in AndroidStudio trying to set an image to display on the screen after it is taken by the camera. This is working flawlessly on the emulator but when I test it on my device (Nexus 5) the image does not show up.

I have tried scaling down my image which didn't work, I also tried using a small image in my drawables folder to make sure it wasn't a file path issue (the drawable image also displayed on the emulator but not on my phone). I also tried converting the bitmap to a drawable and setting it to the background of the imageView which also didn't work. I am not sure what else to try at this point.

EDIT: I should add that if I explicitly add the image in the XML as a background it will show up on my device which makes me think it is my java. On the other hand I can get the image to show up on another activity with this same java code which makes me think it is the layout.

```
File file = cameraShot;
ImageView leftEye = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ghostAlign);
if(leftEye != null) {
  Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
  leftEye.setImageBitmap(bmp);
}
```

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/cameraFrag"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:foreground="?selectableItemBackground"
    android:tag="ScopiCamera"
    tools:ignore="UnusedAttribute">


    <FitTextureView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/texture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ghostAlign"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"
        android:alpha="0.5" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: There is not enough info here to debug, first try setting a drawable using `src` tag on imageview, then try setting that image using `setImageDrawable` and see if it works. these will narrow down the problem you are experiencing

Comment: @KayvanN Setting a drawable using a src tag on imageview works on both the emulator and the device. When I use setImageDrawable it only works on the emulator (which to me makes no sense).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to see if there is no memory problem due to loading your image. See [this page](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/load-bitmap.html) from doc in order to reduce memory consumption when loading your image.

I had this problem too, the image was opened on other devices but not on my phone. Maybe by properly loading your bitmap, it will works.

Answer (score 1):

first check

google photo in nexus5 enable status?

if google photo setting's disable

can't file path's use & file open

(check : use file maneger on  "file.getAbsolutePath()" )

can't gallery use, naxus's google account disable status

--

second
 textureView no use'd check

next code possible?

public class MainActivity extends Activity{

```
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;
ImageView leftEye;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    leftEye = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ghostAlign);
    dispatchTakePictureIntent();

}

private void dispatchTakePictureIntent() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();

        if(leftEye != null) {

            Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
            leftEye.setImageBitmap(imageBitmap);

        }

    }
}
```

}

if  Bitmap on imageview's see.
i think,  AbsolutePath error