# ImageView shows on Emulator but NOT on device. Image on device is invisible

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

**My problem**
I have some dynamically created imageViews in which I put a drawable (xml vector, SVG). Everything seems to be OK on the android emulator but when I load the app on my phone there is no image visible. I know the image is there because if I increment its size, the views on the right at on the left move to the side. So there is an image!

**What I have tried**

- Check memory of the phone
- Use android:src and app:sourceCompat for the imageViews
- Convert Drawable into Bitmap
- Load another image (which is doing well in another window)
- Put the drawable file in another drawable-folder
- Change the layout type from RelativeLayout to LinearLayout
- Read all the similar posts... No one resolves my problem :(

> My class RankingDialog extends from AlertDialog.Builder
>
> My layout is a RelativeLayout but I don't think that this causes the issue...

***Create the views***

---

```
for (int i = 0; i < LocalNames.size(); i++){
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(context); 

        layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        TextView position = new TextView(context);
        TextView name = new TextView(context);
        TextView record = new TextView(context);

        position.setTypeface(font);
        name.setTypeface(font);
        record.setTypeface(font);

        position.setText(i+1 + ".");
        position.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        name.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        record.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        position.setLayoutParams(tvPosParams);
        layout.addView(position);

        name.setText(LocalNames.get(i));
        name.setLayoutParams(tvNameParams);
        layout.addView(name);

        //Here is where I create and load the imageView/image
        ImageView flag = new ImageView(context);
        flag.setLayoutParams(imageParams);
        flag.setImageResource(context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.myImage);
        layout.addView(flag);

        record.setText(LocalPoints.get(i));
        record.setLayoutParams(tvPointsParams);
        layout.addView(record);

        mainLinear.addView(layout);
    }
```

----------
**Emulator (How it should look like)**
[image: The end result should look like this]

 
**How it looks on any real device...**
[image: This is how my issue looks like...]

***I'm stuck for a couple of weeks here. I can't understand why this is happening... 

I will apreciate any help***

Comment: Probable issue with difference in screen size. Add ss of both the outputs.

Comment: Question edited !

Comment: Why not you use [`RecyclerView`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview)?

Comment: try posting your xml here

Comment: What is `imageParams`?

Comment: imageParams are the layoutParams of the image

Comment: This may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42964929/android-imageview-displays-on-emulator-but-not-on-device/42966054#42966054

Comment: why don't you dynamically resize the image to required size?

Comment: I have allready check memory of the device and resized the image dynamically but there is no difference... The image stills "invisible"